# How to create a keyboard accelerator struct using dot notation

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

I'm a C/C++ newbie so I could use some help with understanding *why* this doesn't work, rather than a different way to do what I'm trying to do here. I'm trying to create a basic Windows application and want to make use of keyboard accelerators.

```
typedef struct tagACCEL { // accl 
    BYTE   fVirt; 
    WORD   key; 
    WORD   cmd; 
} ACCEL;
```

This is the format of the struct that they need to be in. Ok, no problem. I try to declare my struct and assign values to each member:

```
ACCEL foo;
foo.fVirt = FVIRTKEY;
foo.key = VK_RETURN;
```

But this is what I see in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

I don't understand. What I did is how you declare a struct and assign member values, no? The "show potential fixes" was of no help by the way. I tried.

Comment: `foo.fVirt = FVIRTKEY;` is a statement, which can only appear inside a function definition body.

Comment: Did you include Windows.h? Is this code inside a function?

Comment: It wasn't inside a function, that must have been the problem.

Comment: ACCEL Already define in `WinUser.h`, you need delete your struct define. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-accel